# When Windows cursor has the spinning animation, what is actually happening?

Tags: c, windows

I recently made a small Windows program in C that constantly sets the thread execution state to ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED.

```
int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        result = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);
        Sleep(30 * 1000);
    }

    //unreachable
    return 0;
}
```

This is essentially all my program is (excluding includes and #define). However, when I run my program the Windows cursor "loading" animation runs for a good few seconds - what's actually happening here? What tells the OS to "run the loading cursor animation"?

Comment: How long is a good few seconds? When does it do it? Does it repeat?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch It happens once, when I start the program, for 3 seconds. It doesn't repeat

Comment: With the code you give, I'm not reproducing this on Windows 10 latest, x64. It may be due to your OS config or 3rd parties installed.

Comment: @SimonMourier I can reproduce it on Windows 10 Version 1909, and Windows 7 (latest). Anyway the question isn't about my code.

Comment: A native Windows program gets 6 seconds to start up and create its first window.  The arrow+hourglass cursor is displayed as long as that didn't happen yet.  You never create a window, so the timeout value applies.  Why the entrypoint is main() and not WinMain() is not obvious, and the probable reason why Simon couldn't get the repro.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you that makes sense actually - do you have an official source for this?

Comment: Yes, I tried a console app of course, this is caused "process feedback cursor" see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa#remarks and a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857054/turning-off-process-feedback-cursor-in-windows